# Set thead th width equal to tbody

Tags: javascript, jquery

After setting the `<thead>` of a table `position:fixed`, the width is not the same as the `<tbody> <td>`. I tried to fix this, with this jQuery code:

```
$("#table tbody td:first td").each(function(i) {
  $("#table thead th:last th").eq(i).width($(this).outerWidth());
});
```

But it doesn't work. Why is the width gone after setting position to fixed?

Comment: `position: fixed` assumes an automatic width. When you say the code you posted doesn't work, what do you mean?

Comment: Post your table (or part), because that is apparently where it goes wrong.